# Second Order Sequence in python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to create a second order sequence in python.

There are 4 optional cases `[1,2,3,4]`.
I would be great if each case occurs equally often. If that is not possible, well...

Importantly, I want to control for second ordering.
This means: Depending on the last two numbers, only 2 numbers are allowed to follow.

I will give two examples: 
If the sequence is `[...1,1,...]` only 3 or 4 is possible.
If the sequence is `[...3,4,...]` only 1 or 2 is possible.
[I have these restrictions for all possibilities. Of course. But i think when i have a code for two of them i can adapt it for the rest.]

The sequence should look something like that with a length of ca. 120 cases:
seq = `[2,4,3,3,1,3,2,...]`

Any suggestions how to create such a sequence?

Comment: Does the order of the previous elements matter: say the sequence is `[...,4,3,...]` are the only possibilities still 1 and 2.

Comment: Is there anything related to Python we could help with?  Right now this isn't so much a question as a specification.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: Yes the order matters. E.g. [...,4,3,...] only 3 and 4. [...3,4,...] only 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first construct a dictionary that shows the possible next elements:

```
nexts = {
         (1,1):(3,4),
         (3,4):(1,2),
         # ...
        }
```

So this means that given the previous numbers are `(1,1)`, then the next element is one of `(3,4)` (so 3 or 4). Next we can generate a sequence. Since you did not specify anything about the first numbers, I will assume these are *random*. You can construct:

```
from random import choice

def second_order_random(k,next_dic):
    n0 = choice(range(1,k+1))
    yield n0
    n1 = choice(range(1,k+1))
    yield n1
    while True:
        (n0,n1) = (n1,choice(next_dic[(n0,n1)]))
        yield n1
```

This is an infinite generator that will yield elements according to the specifications of you `nexts`. `k` on the other hand specifies the range of the numbers (here `k=4`). So when you call `second_order_random(4,nexts)`, you can generate a sequences of the form:

```
3,4,2,...
1,1,4,...
1,1,3,...
3,4,1,...
```

Now you only need to generate 120 elements from the generator and put them in a list. You can do this with:

```
from iteratools import islice

result = list(islice(second_order_random(4,nexts),120))
```

If one does this with:

```
nexts = {(1,1):(2,),(1,2):(1,2),(2,1):(1,),(2,2):(1,)}
k = 2
```

one for instance gets:

```
>>> list(islice(second_order_random(k,nexts),10))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

So `nexts` here specified that `(1,1)` is always followed by a `2`, that `(1,2)` can be followed any number and that `(2,1)` and `(2,2)` are always followed by `1`. This is of course a small example to demonstrate that it works. Because of the `next` constraints, this lists will always collapse eventually tot `...,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,...`

Comment: This works fine.
nexts = {
  (1,1):(3,4),
  (1,2):(3,4),
  (1,3):(1,2),
  (1,4):(1,2),
  (2,1):(1,2),
  (2,2):(1,2),
  (2,3):(3,4),
  (2,4):(3,4),
  (3,1):(3,4),
  (3,2):(3,4),
  (3,3):(1,2),
  (3,4):(1,2),
  (4,1):(1,2),
  (4,2):(1,2),
  (4,3):(3,4),
  (4,4):(3,4),
  }

Comment: Do you also see an option to control for the frequency of each number. So that each occurs equally often?

Comment: @SDahm: it will uniformly pick out of the `next` possible states. It is simply impossible to enforce that: what if you have `nexts = {(1,1):(1,),(1,2):(1,),(2,1):(1,),(2,2):(1,)}`. In that case the system can only generate ones in the end.