# Creating 12-item second order sequence number generator

Tags: python, pycharm, sequence

I'm very new to coding so I apologize if this is an obvious question. I am trying to create some code that will create a 12-item long sequence of numbers that comply with certain constraints:

1. Each number repeats the same amount of times
2. No single number repeats (can't have 1-1)
3. No number pair repeats (can't have 1-2 followed by 1-2)

I had tried working off of a second order condition question asked back in 2017 ([Second Order Sequence in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367743/second-order-sequence-in-python)), but I can't get it to work. Here is the code I've been editing:

```
from random import choice

def second_order_random(k,SOC):
    n0 = choice(range(1,k+1))
    yield n0
    n1 = choice(range(1,k+1))
    yield n1
    while True:
        (n0,n1) = (n1,choice(SOC[(n0,n1)]))
        yield n1

# dictionary defining valid sequences
SOC = {
    (1, 2):(3, 4),
    (1, 2):(4, 3),
    (1, 3):(2, 4),
    (1, 3):(4, 2),
    (1, 4):(2, 3),
    (1, 4):(3, 2),
    (2, 1):(3, 4),
    (2, 1):(4, 3),
    (2, 3):(1, 4),
    (2, 3):(4, 1),
    (2, 4):(1, 3),
    (2, 4):(3, 1),
    (3, 1):(2, 4),
    (3, 1):(4, 2),
    (3, 2):(1, 4),
    (3, 2):(4, 1),
    (3, 4):(1, 2),
    (3, 4):(2, 1),
    (4, 1):(2, 3),
    (4, 1):(3, 2),
    (4, 2):(1, 3),
    (4, 2):(3, 1),
    (4, 3):(1, 2),
    (4, 3):(2, 1)
}
for n in second_order_random(4, SOC):
    print(n)
```

If I try to replace the 'k' with any value (I tried 4 to try and follow the example) I get a "SyntaxError: Invalid syntax" output otherwise it does nothing at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where did you replace `k`? You can't replace it in the function parameter list, parameters are always variables.

Comment: Show how you're using the function. It should be something like `for n in second_order_random(4, SOC):`

Comment: Your first problem is that you've defined your function, but you haven't called it. (You may or may not have further problems,  but nothing will happen till you call it.)

Comment: In the original example it uses iteratools, but I was told by my PI not to use that toolbox. I thought maybe the issue was in the definition of the function. I have the call function as: for n in second_order_random(4, SOC):
    print(n)

Comment: The numbers are generating now, but infinitely. Is there a good way to stop the loops after 12 items are generated without using iteratools?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how many numbers you want to use, but for 12 the minimum is apparently 3. Here's a simple backtracking algorithm, which creates a list of candidates for the "next" number, excludes those violating the requirements and attempts to fill the rest of the list. If this fails, it backtracks and picks the next possible candidate:

```
import random

def fill(src, dst=None):
    # print(src, ' >> ', dst)

    if not src:
        return dst

    dst = dst or []

    free = set(src)
    if len(dst) > 0:
        free.discard(dst[-1])
    if len(dst) > 2 and dst[-1] == dst[-3]:
        free.discard(dst[-2])

    while free:
        n = random.choice(list(free))
        free.remove(n)
        src2 = list(src)
        src2.remove(n)
        dst2 = fill(src2, dst + [n])
        if dst2:
            return dst2
    

##

src = [1, 2, 3] * 4
res = fill(src)
print(res)

# for example, [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful! I was able to edit it so it ran for [1, 2, 3, 4] as well. If I wanted each sequence to start with a particular pair (ex. "1, 2...") is that sort of constraint possible to add in?

Comment: sure, you can start with any combination of `src` (=remaining elements) and `dst` (=resulting sequence).

Comment: e.g `fill([3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], [1,2])`